# curl CLI to curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

I use the following command in some old scripts:

```
curl -Lk "https:www.example.com/stuff/api.php?"
```

I then record the header into a variable and make comparisons and so forth.  What I would really like to do is convert the process to PHP.  I have enabled curl, openssl, and believe I have everything ready.

What I cannot seem to find is a handy translation to convert that command line syntax to the equivalent commands in PHP.

I suspect something in the order of :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// What goes here so that I just get the Location and nothing else?

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Get the response and close the channel.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The goal being $response = the data from the api “OK=1&ect”

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your comment:

```
// What goes here so that I just get the Location and nothing else?
```

Anyway, if you want to obtain the response body from the remote server, use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

If you want to get the headers in the response (i.e.: what your comment might be referring to):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

If your problem is that there is a redirection between the initial call and the response, use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: However, $response = 1 when I echo it.

Comment: Is $response === true? What's the output of `var_dump($response)`?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); works for what I am doing.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @user510025 please mark this as the accepted answer (by clicking the tick icon to the left). Welcome to Stack Overflow!